# How to implement the action of (everything EXCEPT a specific one) in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im trying to create a concentration type of game where if two cards don't match set them back to a blank image.  Im however stuck on the part on how to say if a specific card isn't selected set all cards back to a blank image **EXCEPT** the ones that the user has already matched.

```
  private void tbtnCard3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    tbtnCard3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Card3Logo.png")));
    if(tbtnCard5.isSelected()){
        score++;
        lblScore.setText(""+score);
    } else{
//set all cards to BlankImage.png, except the matched cards
}                                         

private void tbtnCard4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     tbtnCard4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Card7EWaste.png")));
    if(tbtnCard7.isSelected()){
        score++;
        lblScore.setText(""+score);
    }
}                                         

private void tbtnCard5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     tbtnCard5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Card3Logo.png")));
    if(tbtnCard3.isSelected()){
        score++;
        lblScore.setText(""+score);
    }
}
```

Would I have to create an array of all the cards?

Comment: You already asked another question with the same question, just different title. Why ask a second one? Instead edit the previous one

Comment: Note, if you didn't get an answer with your first question then the requirement is not clear and repeating the same question generally won't help. The question needs to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have some kind of "Card" class, you can give it another attribute `boolean matched` and a function `isMatched()` which states if the card is already matched. At the point of the game, when you want to reset the cards, you can iterate over all open cards and reset only if the `isMatched()` method returns `false`.